# Android: Como usar PostAtTime?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hola Necesito ejecutar un metodo en una fecha en especifica lei que PostAtTime me ayudaria en eso pero no se como especificar esa fecha en uptimeMillis

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postAtTime({
                texto.text = "Testo ha cambiado"
            },uptimeMillis)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para usar un [handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Handler), debes definir en cuantos milisegundos se ejecutara,

```
 mHandler.postDelayed(
                        mRunnable, // Runnable
                        1000 // Delay en milisegundos
                )
```

Por lo tanto, no se puede definir directamente una fecha, pero en este caso lo que puedes realizar es definir la fecha en la cual deseas se ejecute y convertirla en milisegundos para restarle la fecha en milisegundos cuando inicia el Handler, de esta forma podrás configurar cuando se ejecutaría.

```
          //Define fecha en la cual se ejecutara el Handler. 
          val myDate = "2020/12/12 12:09:50"
          val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
          val date: Date = sdf.parse(myDate)
          //Obtiene fecha en milisegundos
          val futureDateToMillis: Long = date.getTime()

          //Variable que indica en cuantos milisegundos se llamara proceso
          var uptimeMillis : Long = 0
          var currentDateTime :Long = System.currentTimeMillis()

          //Obtiene diferencia de fecha definida menos fecha actual en millisegundos
          uptimeMillis = futureDateToMillis - currentDateTime;
          printFecha("Diferencia", uptimeMillis);


          Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
              // Se imprimira en 2020/12/12 12:09:50"             
              System.out.println("¡Hola Jorgesys!")

          }, uptimeMillis)
```